# PHP Composer auto load error

Tags: php, composer-php

Recently I've updated my composer to 1.0.3. After that I'm getting following error. "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Error"

Here is my sample code.

```
<?php
require "./vendor/autoload.php";

require "MyErrorLog.php"; // Class file having class name as "Error"
```

Previously, I was using some code without having any problem. But, after updating composer & it's dependance I'm getting this error.

Shall I need to use a namespace to resolve this or something else I need to do?

If I use following the piece of code.

```
require "./vendor/autoload.php";

$Error = new Error();

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($Error);
echo '</pre>';
```

I'm getting this out put.

```
Error Object
(
    [message:protected] => 
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/testing/composer-test1/composer-test.php
    [line:protected] => 7
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Anyone, help me to understand what's exactly it is & what it's uses?

Adding my composer.json file content

```
{
    "require": {
        "defuse/php-encryption": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the error message your have a naming collision.  Put your `Error` class behind a namespace and it should go away.  In a perfect world you should have all of your code behind a namespace to prevent collisions.

Comment: @Crackertastic : Thanks for the quick reply. I think your solution will work. Can you tell me one more thing why composer autoload including an "Error" class by default, which was not there in earlier version & how someone will able to use it.

Comment: My guess is one of the packages you are using already declared an `Error` class or you have mistakenly declared it twice.  Normally this is easy enough to spot in your own code if you keep to making your classes share their name with their file name.

Comment: @Crackertastic : My code has exactly 2 lines as it shown in my top post. So, there is no way I'm declaring my 'Error' class twice. I've also updated my post regarding composer autoload's default loading of a "Error" class. You can have a check.

Comment: I don't believe that Composer has an `Error` class out in global space.  I use the .phar file for Composer and a quick run through its files didn't show an `Error` class.  As I said, it would seem like one of your dependencies is using declaring an `Error` class already.  The easier (and best practice) is to simply namespace all your code.  That will minimize the risk of a name collision.  I would also suggest you make your class names the same as your file name.  This allows you to autoload your own code with composer instead of the extra `require` statements that you are using.

Comment: @Crackertastic : I've updated my post with composer dependencies list. What I also saw is.. that "Error" class in global scope is coming from ```defuse/php-encryption``` library. Whenever I'm including this library it's started showing error & the moment I'm removing this dependency from composer no more error is coming.

Comment: Based on what you have posted and comments that would appear to be the issue.  Your choices at this point are to either namespace your code (this is something you should do anyway) so that the two `Error` classes can co-exist ... or ... find an alternate library that doesn't collide with your class names.  Personally, I suggest doing the former.

Comment: Yeah, Agree with you.